# EpsonUSBDisplay: интерактивность проектора - синий экран

Tags: драйвер, ubuntu

Фирма не производит драйверов под Ubuntu к проектору SB 460i. Похоже, никто не производит.Интерактивность проектора - синий экран. Можно ли исправить это?

Answer (score 1):

С уверенностью 99% могу сказать что нет.